# How to get stats on go packages?

Tags: go

I am trying to track and understand the download stats for various go packages to evaluate the download patter over time for the go driver published and released by my team. 
Something similar to npm-stats
https://npm-stat.com/

I see similar stats available for `pip-python` and `npm`. 
https://npm-stat.com/

Comment: Go packages can be hosted anywhere, in various different types of repositories, which are under no obligation or expectation to record or publish any metrics on how often they're checked out or by whom.

Comment: Some stats are available here for individual packages: https://pkg.go.dev/

Answer (score 4):

That may happen once the Go Notary service described in "[Go Modules in 2019](https://blog.golang.org/modules2019)" is in place:

> For publicly-available modules, we intend to run a service we call a notary that follows the module index log, downloads new modules, and cryptographically signs statements of the form “module M at version V has file tree hash H.” The notary service will publish all these notarized hashes in a queryable, [Certificate Transparency](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/)-style [tamper-proof log](http://static.usenix.org/event/sec09/tech/full_papers/crosby.pdf), so that anyone can verify that the notary is behaving correctly.
>   This log will serve as a public, global `go.sum` file that go get can use to authenticate modules when adding or updating dependencies.

[image: https://blog.golang.org/modules2019/code.png]

> We are aiming to have the go command check notarized hashes for publicly-available modules not already in go.sum starting in Go 1.13.

If statistics were to be produced, the Go notary would be a reliable source (for public packages)

Answer (score 2):

Go doesn't have a centralized package registry such as npm or pip.

Also, go dependency management is still not "unified", some use `dep` some `glide` or `go mod`. All of these rely on version control software such as git.

If your package is on Github, you could check the Insights > Traffic tab and see unique cloners for example.

Another solution might be to implement a proxy to your git server to track clones.

Answer (score 0):

You Can't do this.
As those are developed as part of Go language. Like npm packages you are not downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

try gocenter.io, it includes download stats for all modules available. Example - logrus was downloaded 544k+ times - https://search.gocenter.io/github.com~2Fsirupsen~2Flogrus/info?version=v1.4.3-0.20191026113918-67a7fdcf741f

Comment: This is no longer valid as is looks like JFrog acquired the domain.